# Radio button is not rendered correctly while upgrading from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-c++, themes, visual-studio-2019

I upgraded my `Visual Studio 2008` to `Visual Studio 2019`. I build my project in `VS 2019` and ran the application. Everything is fine except Radio Buttons are not rendered properly. **Radio buttons are rendered black with their labels**. Also, I have upgraded the CodeJock dlls from 1640 to 1900 to support the themes. It can be a theme issue in Visual Studio 2019.

Additional Details:

> Desktop application in VC++.
>  
>   Currently my application has a XTPRibbonTheme
>   OS: 64x
>   Windows 10

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Try this thing: uninstall all themes or reset them, if possible. Check the appropriate rendering. Then install them again.

Comment: How to uninstall or reset those themes?

Comment: Well, don't know, just my thoughts. Another thing: try to create and play with a single form application including a single radio button, to boil out the essence of the problem.

Comment: Could you please provide us with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)to reproduce the issue.

Comment: It is broken for the Radio Buttons used under CXTPTabControl tabs only. Otherwise it is rendering fine for normal Radio Button.